# mapping capslock to ctrl on centos

Tags: keyboard, emacs, centos

How can I map <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on CentOS. It's a CentOS server that I SSH into so there isn't a window manager or anything like that.

Comment: capslock is configured by your local keyboard, not a remote server.  What OS are you sshing **from**?

Answer (score 0):

Darren's comment helped me figure it out. I'm on OS X and this SO answer solved the problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162896/emacs-on-mac-os-x-leopard-key-bindings